# Unable to paste PHP code into HTML section of PHP document?

Tags: php, implementation

How can I place this code: `$image_url = get_company_field( 'company_office_photo' );
echo '<img src="' . $image_url '" />';`

into the one below. I tried using `<div>` selectors but with no luck and was getting syntax error. Any help appreciated.

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying job listings (in a loop).
 *
 * @package Listify
 */
?>

<li id="job_listing-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php job_listing_class(); ?> <?php echo apply_filters(
'listify_job_listing_data', '', false ); ?>>

 <div class="content-box">

  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="job_listing-clickbox"></a>

  <header <?php echo apply_filters( 'listify_cover', 'job_listing-entry-header listing-cover' ); ?>>
            <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_header_before' ); ?>

**/* I want to place the code in this line */**

   <div class="job_listing-entry-header-wrapper cover-wrapper">
    
    <div class="job_listing-entry-thumbnail">
     <div <?php echo apply_filters( 'listify_cover', 'list-cover' ); ?>></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="job_listing-entry-meta">
     <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_meta' ); ?>
    </div>

   </div>

            <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_header_after' ); ?>
  </header><!-- .entry-header -->

  <footer class="job_listing-entry-footer">

   <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_footer' ); ?>

  </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

 </div>
</li><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: Wrap your code between <?php ?> tags and place it where you want

Comment: @batz When I do that I am getting this error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''" />'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data01/98/3246698/html/wp-content/themes/listify/content-job_listing.php on line 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<li id="job_listing-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php job_listing_class(); ?> <?php  echo apply_filters(
'listify_job_listing_data', '', false ); ?>>

<div class="content-box">

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="job_listing-clickbox"></a>

    <header <?php echo apply_filters( 'listify_cover', 'job_listing-entry-header listing-cover' ); ?>>
        <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_header_before' ); ?>

         <?php $image_url = get_company_field( 'company_office_photo' ); ?>
             <img src="<?php echo $image_url ?>" />

        <div class="job_listing-entry-header-wrapper cover-wrapper">

            <div class="job_listing-entry-thumbnail">
                <div <?php echo apply_filters( 'listify_cover', 'list-cover' ); ?>></div>
            </div>

            <div class="job_listing-entry-meta">
                <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_meta' ); ?>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_header_after' ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <footer class="job_listing-entry-footer">

        <?php do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_footer' ); ?>

    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

</div>
```